# Unable to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.10 - packages have been kept back: libgd-dev libgd3 libgd3:i386

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, update-manager

I'm on Ubuntu 22.10 unable to uprade. I tried all that I could find:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt full-upgrade
```

Here is the log:

```
hp@hp-workstation:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.10
Release:    22.10
Codename:   kinetic


hp@hp-workstation:/etc/apt$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                                                                                                                                                                             
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                              
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                
Ign:5 https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                   
Hit:6 https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release                                                                                                                                                                                     
Hit:7 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                     
Hit:9 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                       
Hit:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                            
Hit:11 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                                                                                                                                                                               
Hit:12 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                         
Hit:13 https://apt.syncthing.net syncthing InRelease                                                                                                                   
Hit:14 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/alex-p/tesseract-ocr-devel/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:15 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                     
Hit:16 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease                                                          
Get:17 https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_22.10 ./ InRelease [2,961 B]                                      
Hit:18 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease                                                   
Hit:19 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/christian-boxdoerfer/fsearch-stable/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Ign:20 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:21 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/hluk/copyq/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:22 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:23 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/jcfp/nobetas/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Ign:24 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:25 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:26 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu kinetic Release                                                                                                                                                                
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 443]
Err:27 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu kinetic Release                                                                                                                                                                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::3e 443]
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                                                                
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en_IN' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en_GB' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://download.onlyoffice.com/repo/debian squeeze InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:19
W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:29
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:12 and /etc/apt/sources.list:13
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:12 and /etc/apt/sources.list:13
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:12 and /etc/apt/sources.list:21
W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:12 and /etc/apt/sources.list:31
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:40
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:40
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:40
W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:40
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:44
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:44
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:7
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:19
W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:6 and /etc/apt/sources.list:29
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:12 and /etc/apt/sources.list:13
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:12 and /etc/apt/sources.list:13
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:12 and /etc/apt/sources.list:21
W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:12 and /etc/apt/sources.list:31
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:40
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:40
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:40
W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:39 and /etc/apt/sources.list:40
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:44
W: Target Sources (restricted/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:44
W: Target Sources (universe/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: Target Sources (multiverse/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:43 and /etc/apt/sources.list:48



hp@hp-workstation:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libgd-dev libgd3 libgd3:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.





hp@hp-workstation:~$ sudo apt install libgd-dev libgd3 libgd3:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgd3 : Depends: libavif13 (>= 0.9.3) but it is not installable
          Breaks: libgd3:i386 (!= 2.3.3-9+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 2.3.3-6+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
 libgd3:i386 : Breaks: libgd3 (!= 2.3.3-6+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 2.3.3-9+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.



hp@hp-workstation:~$ sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade  libgd-dev libgd3 libgd3:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgd3 : Depends: libavif13 (>= 0.9.3) but it is not installable
          Breaks: libgd3:i386 (!= 2.3.3-9+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 2.3.3-6+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
 libgd3:i386 : Breaks: libgd3 (!= 2.3.3-6+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 2.3.3-9+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages





hp@hp-workstation:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libgd-dev libgd3 libgd3:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10 reached EOL some time ago (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/07/27/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-end-of-life-reached-on-july-20-2023/) so there are no packages to upgrade.

Comment: @guiverc I have tried everything that were suggested in those linked questions. Its still the same. Its unable to update `libgd-dev libgd3 libgd3:i386`. I've updated the log

Comment: You're off-topic with that request. Picking an error on your screen, and using the link from your provided details clearly shows (https://launchpad.net/~flatpak/+archive/ubuntu/stable) that support is provided **only** for LTS releases; *kinetic* was **not** a LTS; being a *snapshot* of the progress towards Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (*development of a LTS covers two years, with 3 snapshots of progress for 24.04 being 22.10, 23.04 & 23.10, work started just after 22.04 was released*)

Comment: @guiverc: I'm a layman when it comes to using Linux/Ubuntu. I didn't understand much from what you said except that  22.10 is not LTS and never will be. And the development cycle is such that after 22.04 only 24.04 will be the LTS version. 

All I want is to get out of this 22.10 but `3 package kept back` is preventing me to do the upgrade. I've copy pasted every command I could find (with half-baked understanding) on the topic nothing worked. Hence I asked the question.

Comment: Your question contains *nothing on-topic for this site*, as only *supported* releases of Ubuntu (not even *development* or ESM releases that don't have *community* support) are on-topic. I suggest you ask on SE *Unix & Linux* which covers all GNU/Linux, BSD and unix like operating systems (*it allows ESM, EOL, *development* too, in fact all releases of Ubuntu).   *You've pollution to sources is your issue; as per your pasted error message*